# LibGDX How do I create a Shop?

Tags: android, libgdx

My game is fully working but now I want to make a shop so that the player can buy boosts or other useful stuff for the money the player has collected.

What is the best way of doing this kind of shops:

*The collected coins you have saved goes up/down in value when you buy something

*The item activates if bought.

Is this possible in libGDX and how can I start?

Comment: are you talking about an in-game only shop or one that has to contact a server to do the transaction (think micro transactions)?

Comment: I'm thinking about an in-game shop where you can spend your 'coins' on items which can later be activated whenever the player want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the values in a database,It is simple if you use database like sqlite but that wont work with libgdx -android.

Instead you can use [gdx-sqlite](https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite)

gdx-sqlite is a cross-platform Libgdx extension for SQLite database handling. The extension abstracts databse handling to provide a unified method to handle database transacitons across multiple platforms while also adding SQLite support for desktop version of Libgdx application.